# Compact Framework and ClearType text

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, cleartype

Is there a way to use ClearType text in an application using the .NET Compact Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to ctacke's answer: You can create a font with ClearType quality on a need-to basis by setting the `Quality` property of `Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.LogFont` to `LogFontQuality.ClearType` and use it to create the font with `Font.FromLogFont()`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply enable ClearType for the platform by setting the following registry entry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\GDI\Cleartype]
    "Default"=dword:00000001
```